# Scroll to top when tap on UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I am having `UITabBarController` in which one of tab has two container view and I want to scroll to top on both controllers in it.

My Base View Controller is `NotificationViewController` and child view controllers are like `NotificationNetworkViewController` and `NotificationPodcastViewController`

I am Using following extension : -

```
extension NotificationNetworkViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        print("Network TAB INDEX : \(tabBarController.selectedIndex)")
        notificationTable.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to achieve your needs. For animation, you just need to pass value true/false in animated of `scrollToRow` function.
Hope this will help you!

**To scroll top without animation**

```
func scrollToBottomWithoutAnimation() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         if self.dataArray.count > 0 {
             let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
             notificationTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
         }
     }
}
```

**To scroll top with animation**

```
func scrollToBottomWithoutAnimation() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         if self.dataArray.count > 0 {
             let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
             notificationTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Only first view controller is working not for second

Comment: `Didn't getting.` Will you please explain in detail?